# retrieving data from the network

Tags: android

I've had an interview and I was given the following code, so that the UserAPI is a utility class for retrieving data from the network.
Assume it operate with its own threading mechanism with no respect to the caller thread.
And I had to find what's wrong with the code:

```
public class NetworkTestActvitiy extends Activity {
    private TextView userNameTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.chegg_test_layout);

        userNameTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.userName);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        loadUserName();
    }

    private void loadUserName() {
        UserAPI.getInstance().getUserName(new NetworkListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(ErrorMessage error) {
                Logger.e("Failed to get user use: " + error.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String userName) {
                userNameTextView.setText(userName);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the call to `userNameTextView.setText` can not be from UI thread and has to be marshalled.